# Stop style from spreading to subtable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table nested inside another table. I have a style assigned to every second tr of both tables, but the problem is the same style also spreads to subtable.

This is my style:

```
.table .collapse-row td {
  border-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

And here is a jsfiddle of the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/42119/

This is a table where every 2nd row is hidden and when i press on a row then the second row expands. The mentioned style is needed so the 2nd row wouldnt take any space while hidden. The problem is that "Value" and the row expands then the subtable row with "Value2" is also affected by my style and thus looses the padding and is smaller than "Value" row.

Here is an image of the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is what the "Cascade" in Cascading Style Sheets stands for. Most of the time you want the style to "Cascade" to children elements. You will have to style the "inner" table directly in order to ignore the style inherited from the parent.

Comment: So i should define another class "regular-row" that overwrites all the properties set by "collapsed-row" and assign it to each tr hat isnt "collapsed-row"? Like this https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/42130/ ?